# Display 'BuddyPress Follow' follow button to non-logged in users

Tags: functions

I'm tring to display 'BuddyPress Follow' follow button to non-registered users.
And when a non-registered user clicks the follow button it redirects him to register page, and after registration he redirect again to the page he clicked the follow button